# Adding multiple images through file upload or any other alternative in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, image, jquery-plugins, file-upload

Just need to know is there any plugins, jquery or any control so that I can add multiple images at least 10 at a time, I need to provide add image section to my client , where he/she can add upto 10 images , 1 being minimum and 10 being maximum, through file upload one can add only 1 image at a time, I am using asp.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the jQuery Option : (Recommended)

http://www.uploadify.com/

This can also help you :

[Upload multiple files with a single file element](http://the-stickman.com/web-development/javascript/upload-multiple-files-with-a-single-file-element/)

Comment: uploadify , looks like a good option for me .. have you tried in on ny of ur .net website

Comment: Yes, I tried it before for some web applications (not public websites) It was good for me.

Comment: It has a good documentation, look at [documentation](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/) its really simple to do

Comment: yeh documentation looks easy , but i want to save the image file into the folder and save the imagename into database, i can do that with file upload , but i dont know how to with this plugin

Comment: if you are using asp.net you take a look at [this video](http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-multiple-file-uploads-in-aspnet-2) and get rid all of these problems.

Comment: This is also a good example of doing it http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/multiple_file_upload.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can try telerik control for mvc. its open source and freeware..

dont need any license for it..

And its very User friends one u configure them..

Refer 
[Download site](http://www.telerik.com/purchase/faqs/aspnet-mvc.aspx)
[Upload Control](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-upload-introduction.html)
[Configuring Telerik Controls](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/getting-started-using-telerik-extensions-for-asp.net-mvc-in-your-project.html)

Navish Rampal
[findnavish.livejournal.com](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/getting-started-using-telerik-extensions-for-asp.net-mvc-in-your-project.html)